# Using jqGrid 4, why is rowid undefined in the event handlers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I'm using jqGrid 4.1.2 in a stand alone grid. I'm seeing an instance where the event handlers are receiving a value of "undefined" as the value for the rowid parameter.

Here's my initialization code.

```
$("#truckGrid").jqGrid({
    url:'/handlers/TruckerCheckDataHandler.ashx',
    datatype: "json",
    colNames:['id','All','VIN', 'Plate', 'Make','Model','Year','RFID #','Description'],
    colModel: [
        {name:'id', index: 'id', hidden:true},
        {name:'action',index:'action', width:25},
        {name:'vin',index:'vin', width:120},
        {name:'plate',index:'plate', width:75},
        {name:'make',index:'make', width:80},
        {name:'model',index:'model', width:80},     
        {name:'year',index:'year', width:40},       
        {name:'rfidNo',index:'rfidNo', width:50},
        {name: 'description', index: 'description', width: 100, sortable: false}                    
    ],
    hidegrid: false,
    jsonReader : {
        root: 'rows',
        repeatitems: false,
        id: 'id',
        page: 'page',
        total: 'total',
        records: 'records'
    },
    nav : {
        edittext: "Edit",
        edittitle: "Edit",
        addtext: "Add Truck",
        addtitle: "Add Truck",
        deltext: "Delete",
        deltitle: "Delete"
    },
    ondblClickRow: function (rowid, iRow, iCol, e) {
        alert(rowid);
    },
    rowNum:10,
    rowList:[10,20,30],
    pager: '#truckPager',
    sortname: 'vin',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: "desc"
});
jQuery("#truckGrid").jqGrid('navGrid','#truckPager',{
    add: true, 
    addfunc: function() {

    },
    del:true, 
    delfunc: function (rowid) {
        alert(rowid);
    },
    editfunc: function (rowid) {
        alert(rowid);
    },
    edit: true, 
    clear:false
});
```

Here is the code that actually adds the truck data to the grid.

```
var _truckList = null;

function truckData (truckId, vin, make, model, year, country, state, plateNum, description, rfid, truckType) {
    return {
        id : truckId,
        vin : vin,
        make : make,
        model : model,
        year : year,
        plateCountry : country,
        plateState : state,
        plateNumber : plateNum,
        description : description,
        rfid : rfid,
        truckType : truckType,
        toJqGridData : function() {
            // [{"DATA_ID":"0", "DATA_DN": "national"}, {"DATA_ID":"1", "DATA_DN": "samsung"}]
                return [{"id":this.id, 'action': '', 'vin':this.vin, 
                    'plate':this.plateCountry + '-' + this.plateState + '-' + 
                    this.plateNumber, 'make':this.make, 'model':this.model, 
                    'year':this.year,'rfidNo':this.rfid, 
                    'description':this.description}]
        }
    };
}


function addTruckData() {
    var addTruck = true;
    var truckVin = $('#truckVin').val();
    if (truckVin.length == 0) {
        return null;
    }

    var rowId = -1;
    var method = '';

    var truck = new truckData (0, truckVin, 
        $('#truckMake').val(), 
        $('#truckModel').val(), 
        $('#truckYear').val(), 
        $('#country').val(), 
        $('#state').val(), 
        $('#truckPlateNumber').val(), 
        $('#truckDescription').val(), 
        $('#truckRfidNo').val(), 
        'OwnerOperator');

    if (_truckList != null) {
        for (var xx = 0; xx < _truckList.length; xx++ ) {
            if (_truckList[xx].vin == truckVin) {
                // The vin is already in the list, update it.
                rowId = xx + 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (rowId == -1 && _truckList == null) {
        _truckList = [ truck ];
        rowId = 1;
        method = 'addRowData';
    }
    else if (rowId == -1) {
        rowId = _truckList.length + 1;
        _truckList.push (truck);
        method = 'addRowData';
    }
    else {
        _truckList[rowId - 1] = truck;
        method = 'setRowData';
    }

    var result = $('#truckGrid').jqGrid(method, rowId, truck.toJqGridData());

    if (!result) {
        alert('Operation failed.');
    }

    // resetTruckFields(); <- Resets the UI state by setting the text boxes to ''
    return truck;
}
```

When the row is double clicked, the event handler fires but the rowid has a value of "undefined".

```
    ondblClickRow: function (rowid, iRow, iCol, e) {
        alert(rowid);
    },
```

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong here but I have no idea what it is. Any thoughts?

The grid is not connected to the data handler at this time and is not making any calls (as expected). Everything is generated locally in java script.

To add a little more clarity, `addTruckData()` is called by code attached to a button, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#doIt').click(function () {
        if ($('form').valid()) {
            addTruckData();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: In the code which you posted the variables or functions `_ctrlId, truckData, _truckType, _truckList, result, resetTruckFields, resolveUrl, editTruck, removeTruck` will be used but not defined. To reproduce the problem with undefined `rowid` parameter of `ondblClickRow` you can try to reduce your code till you have still the problem. To allows other to reproduce your problem you need to post additionally the JSON data returned from `'/handlers/TruckerCheckDataHandler.ashx'`. You can get the data with respect of [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) of [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/).

Comment: I've removed the items in question from the sample.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

After much beating of my head against the proverbial wall, I gotten it to work. Here's the list of differences from the code that does not work with the code that does.

```
    $("#truckGrid").jqGrid({
        // url:resolveUrl('/handlers/TruckerCheckDataHandler.ashx'), <-- Removed because no actual server communication was being utilized.
        datatype: "clientSide", // <-- Should not have been "json", this was happening all client side
        colNames:['id','All','VIN', 'Plate', 'Make','Model','Year','RFID #','Description'],
        colModel: [
            {name:'id', index: 'id', hidden: true},
            {name:'action',index:'action', width:25},
            {name:'vin',index:'vin', width:120},
            {name:'plate',index:'plate', width:75},
            {name:'make',index:'make', width:80},
            {name:'model',index:'model', width:80},     
            {name:'year',index:'year', width:40},       
            {name:'rfidNo',index:'rfidNo', width:50},
            {name: 'description', index: 'description', width: 100, sortable: false}                    
        ],
        datatype: 'local',
        hidegrid: false,
        jsonReader : {
            // root: 'rows',
            repeatitems: false //,
            // id: 'id',
            // page: 'page',
            // total: 'total',
            // records: 'records'
        },
        multiselect : true,
        ondblClickRow: function (rowid) {
            editTruck(rowid);
        },
        rowNum:10,
        rowList:[10,20,30],
        pager: '#truckPager',
        sortname: 'vin',
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "desc"
    });
    $("#truckGrid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#truckPager', {
        edittext: "Edit&nbsp;&nbsp;",
        edittitle: "Edit",
        addtext: "Add Truck&nbsp;&nbsp;",
        addtitle: "Add Truck",
        deltext: "Delete&nbsp;&nbsp;",
        deltitle: "Delete",
        addfunc: function () {
            alert('add');
        },
        delfunc: function (rowid) {
            alert(rowid);
        },
        editfunc: function (rowid) {
            alert(rowid);
        },
        //edit: true,
        clear: false
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't posted any JSON data, so I tried to reproduce your problem with some dummy data. How you can see from [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/amber.htm) I had no success. I mean that all works without any problem. So your problem should be somewhere in another part of your code.

Additionally I moved the settings from `nav` parameter of jqGrid, which is not exist, to other options of `navGrid` and made some other minimal changes. You can see all if you would open the source code of the demo.

Comment: I noticed you didn't try implementing the addTruckData() method. I'm also not starting from a point where there is any data in the grid. At this point, it's empty. I brought all your changes in and the problem still exists. Right now, I'm eyeing "$('#truckGrid').jqGrid(method, rowId, truck.toJqGridData());"

Comment: @amber: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. I just used your code: `addfunc: function() {}` (see the code from your question). I can't use `addTruckData` function because it contains a lot of undefined variables and classes like `truckData`.

Comment: Sorry about, I've added the truckData function. Everything else should be there to support the addTruckData() method.

Comment: @amber: The variable `result` and the function `resetTruckFields` are still undefined. Moreover it's unclear which implementation you use for `addfunc`. The `addTruckData` returns object of the class `truckData`. The method `toJqGridData` of the class `truckData` is undefined. After all that what is the most unclear for me is why the code of `addfunc` should be important for `ondblClickRow`. It could be important only in case that your code destroy some important structures of `$('#truckGrid')`.

Comment: The `result` was missing the "var" and the `toJqGridData` is defined on `truckData` class. `addfunc` is empty for now as it hasn't been implemented yet.

Comment: @amber: If the method `addTruckData` will never used in your code, then your code should work like [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/amber.htm). The demo display rowid correctly. So the code which you posted should be different from the code which you use.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4515/discussion-between-amber-and-oleg)

Comment: @amber: Sorry, but I still don't understand your code. If you hold the data on the server and get it as JSON per Ajax why you need use local add/set of data in the grid with respect of `addRowData` and `setRowData` (I mean the code of `addTruckData` function). The way how you choose the `rowId` in the `addTruckData` seems me wrong and can follow to id duplicates. Moreover all the discussion seens be far from your original question.